# Inflation error when adding gradient to Button

Tags: android, android-button

I'm have a a recyclerview with a book item. This books item has a Button with a custom background, when I add a gradient I get an Inflation error.

book_item.xml>

```
    . . .

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/read_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="Start Reading"

        android:background="@drawable/roundbutton"
        app:backgroundTint="@null" />
    . . .
```

roundbutton.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:endColor="@color/dark_orange"
        android:startColor="@color/orange"
        android:angle="200" />

    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="100px"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="100px"
        android:topRightRadius="100px"
        android:topLeftRadius="100px"/>

</shape>
```

BookAdapterOne.kt

```
class BookAdapterOne(
    private val context: Context,
    private var data: List<Book>,
    private val bookClickListener: BookClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<BookAdapterOne.ItemViewHolder>() {

    class ItemViewHolder(private val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val title: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.book_title)
        val author: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.book_author)
        val description: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.book_description)
        val read_btn: Button = view.findViewById(R.id.read_btn)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
        val adapterLayout = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.book_item, parent, false)

        return ItemViewHolder(adapterLayout)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = data[position]
        holder.title.text = item.title
        holder.author.text = item.author
        holder.description.text = item.description

        holder.read_btn.setOnClickListener {
            bookClickListener.onBookClickListener(item)
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.sapphire.littlered, PID: 5920
> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #51: Error inflating class Button
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:821)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
> at com.sapphire.littlered.adapter.BookAdapterOne.onCreateViewHolder(BookAdapterOne.kt:33)
> at com.sapphire.littlered.adapter.BookAdapterOne.onCreateViewHolder(BookAdapterOne.kt:18)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7078)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
> at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16992)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
> at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1077)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16992)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16992)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16992)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16992)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
> at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16992)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
> at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
> at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16992)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5409)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2483)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2185)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1314)
> at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7057)
> at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:829)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:606)
> at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:576)
> at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:815)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(
> I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5920 SIG: 9

I'm testing on **api 21** (minSdk), and using MaterialComponents theme.

Comment: Can you please send the full error description and its stack trace? It is usually a lot more descriptive about what exactly went wrong. (You may have to scroll a little to the bottom in order to read and copy it in its entirety.)

Comment: I edited the post with the full error.